# Search for Emacs when using Alpine Linux

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

I am trying to test some software on Alpine Linux. I need to make some configuration changes so I need Emacs. `emacs` is the name of the package per [Alpine Linux | Emacs](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/emacs). `apk add emacs` is failing due to missing package.

According to [Alpine Linux package management | Search for Packages](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Search_for_Packages) I am supposed to be able to locate the package with one of these commands:

```
$ apk search emacs
$

$ apk search -v emacs
$

$ apk search -v 'emacs*' 
$
```

What is the name of the Emacs package in Alpine Linux? Or, if the name is correct, how do I install it?

---

Here's the error I am trying to work around. I assume I have the wrong package name, and I need something like `emacs-24.5` or `emacs-nox`.

```
# apk add emacs
ERROR: unsatisfied constraints
  emacs (missing)
    required by: world[emacs]
```

Comment: The package name seems right. Which Alpine version?

Comment: I think you’re missing the community repository in ‘/etc/apk/repositories’ (ships as commented out)

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite a bit old, but a detailed answer can still be helpful for those who reach it. You have to make sure that the `community` package source is enabled and that your packages list is up to date.

- Start by editing the repositories file

```
# vi /etc/apk/repositories/
```

- Since emacs package is [listed in the community repository](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=emacs&branch=edge), make sure that it has the `community` line uncommented, using [one of the available mirrors](https://mirrors.alpinelinux.org/), possibly one that is closer  to your location can be potentially faster to interact with.

```
http://<MIRROR_ADDRESS>/alpine/v<VERSION>/main
http://<MIRROR_ADDRESS>/alpine/v<VERSION>/community
[...]
```

- Make sure that the packages list is up to date.

```
# apk update
```

- Install the desired package, in this case, `emacs`.

```
# apk add emacs
```

It is usually not a problem, but if at this point the issue is still not resolved, also check in the [alpine packages search](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages) if the package is available for your correct computer architecture (can be checked  on terminal with `uname -m`) and operating system version (can be checked on terminal with `cat /etc/os-release`).